# Localization of WP theme

Tags: search, translation, localization, xgettext

I am working on WP theme localization. On custom search template I have function which gets text of some search terms and replace them with other (just visually).

```
function search_replace_search() {
$search_term = esc_attr( apply_filters( 'the_search_query', get_search_query( false ) ) ); // Get search term
$search = array('word1', 'word2' );
$replace = array('something 1', 'something 2' );
$replacePairs = array_combine($search, $replace);
echo strtr($search_term, $replacePairs); 
} 

echo search_replace_search();
```

How to wrap search orreplace words, or function output (echo), so WP will use translation of words (in this example "something 1" and "something 2") from theme's .mo files.
I 've tried various ways to wrap this into gettext, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the elements of `$search` and `$replace` arrays into `__()` function to get the translated strings:

```
function search_replace_search() {
    $search_term = esc_attr( apply_filters( 'the_search_query', get_search_query( false ) ) ); // Get search term

    $search = array(
        __('word1'),
        __('word2')
    );

    $replace = array(
        __('something 1'),
        __('something 2')
    );

    $replacePairs = array_combine($search, $replace);
    echo strtr($search_term, $replacePairs); 
} 

echo search_replace_search();
```

If you use your own `textdomain`:

```
    $search = array(
        __('word1', 'my_textdomain'),
        __('word2', 'my_textdomain')
    );

    $replace = array(
        __('something 1', 'my_textdomain'),
        __('something 2', 'my_textdomain')
    );
```

More information:

- [__() function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2)
- [Very good reference on internationalization](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/)
- [WordPress Internationalization](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/)